# TypeError: require.extensions.hasOwnProperty is not a function - on running gulp

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, gulp, node-modules, laravel-elixir

I was trying to run `gulp` inside my project directory. I have gone through so many articles. Also try running most of given commands (as solutions) in `cmd`. But the same **problem** occurs.

```
if (!require.extensions.hasOwnProperty(ext)) {
                         ^
TypeError: require.extensions.hasOwnProperty is not a function
```

This is how my **`package.json`** looks like.

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "laravel-elixir": "^2.3.13"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.5.2",
    "require-dir": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

It would be great if anyone can help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found an answer. 
I just changed the below code line in `<project>/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/require-dir/index.js` file.

```
if (!require.extensions.hasOwnProperty(ext)) {
```

as:

```
if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(require.extensions, ext)) {
```

And it finally works now.

Comment: This is not recommended, cause you shouldn't modify files inside node_modules. Whenever you update a package, your changes could be removed. Your problem seems to be what is being discussed in this issue: https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates/issues/363#issuecomment-308452577

Comment: Thanks for the information @Thiago. But I've gone through this discussion also. It didn't work for me either. Couldn't found a better solution than this.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by using a lesser version of node.  I was getting this error when using node v 8.9.1.  Fixed it by downgrading to 6.5.0.  I use NVM to swap behind versions